# disappearing <form> tag when using knockoutJS Twitter Bootstrap in custom DNN module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, dotnetnuke

Say I have this simple example of a form

```
<form class="form-horizontal"> 
      <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
         <input size="16" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: startDate" />
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
       </div>

       <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
              <input size="16" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: endDate" />
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
       </div>
</form>
```

When I load the page, bindings and inputs work as expected but the `<form>` tags are missing:

```
   <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
     <input size="16" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: startDate" />
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>                   
   <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
          <input size="16" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: endDate" />
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
```

This causes some bootstrap-related css to not get applied to the form inputs.
Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: Please put this HTML and the JavaScript code you got so far on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: it's a bit difficult to add everything in a fiddle as this is an extracted simplified part of a bigger app. I thought that someone might have an idea if this has anything to do with knockout/bootstrap working together. If not I guess I have to look somewhere else in the app

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to really say why this is happening.  I don't think it's knockout though.  It looks like there's some 3rd party UI form widget that's trying to format your HTML and is inadvertently removing the <form> tag.  When does the <form> tag go missing?  Before or after ko.applyBindings?  The answer to that should start to narrow down when/where this is happening.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. This code is inside a DNN module, so it's already inside a form, thus no nested form is allowed. I forgot that I was working in DNN. Maybe this helps someone else trying to combine all these frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNN is ASP.Net webforms based therefore only one form per page is allowed. Replace the `<form>` tags with `<div>` tags and it should work.

Comment: You can't "nest" forms, and because of the way DNN works, the Form essentially wraps around everything, including modules

Comment: yeap I spoted the mistake in my last comment yesterday. That's why I changed the title of the question to better describe it and have a proper answer in case anyone else has the same issue